# How to go another page when I press settings button on action bar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, settings, android-settings

I face a problem when I try press the settings icon on action bar and go to settings page in my android project.

Here is the code:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.settings) {
            startActivity(new Intent(ProfileFragment.this, SettingsActivity.class));
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

The error is in ProfileFragment.this, SettingsActivity.class line. There is no fatal error but there is a red line under the code.

How can I solve this?

Thanks for answers.

Comment: Pass context at  startActivity(new Intent("context", SettingsActivity.class));

Comment: tried but there is still error.

Comment: pass this getActivity().getApplicationContext();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.settings) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getContext(), SettingsActivity.class));
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
startActivity(new Intent(ProfileFragment.this, SettingsActivity.class));
```

to :

```
startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), SettingsActivity.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

            if(item.getItemId() == R.id.settings) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), SettingsActivity.class));
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```